# Returning variables from Model to other ViewControllers

Tags: swift, oop, model

I am making a weather application. I basically created a class where I will only get data from API and return them as needed. I have variables like `cityName`, `currentWeather` etc.
Problem is sometimes API doesn't provide them all so I need to check if they are nil or not before return them. What comes to my mind is set variables like this first:

```
private var cityNamePrivate: String!
```

and then

```
var cityNamePublic: String {

if cityNamePrivate == nil {
    // 
}
else { return cityNamePrivate }
```

But as you can as imagine, its very bad because I have a lots of variables. Is there any better logic for this? Should I just return them and check later in wherever I send them?

Comment: In `cityNamePublic`, what do you intend to do if `cityNamePrivate` is nil?

Comment: My bad I didn't write that part. Return an empty string like ""

Comment: See [this article](https://jierong.dev/2021/02/26/providing-default-value-for-decodable-property-by-property-wrapper.html).

Comment: You could consider making a dictionary rather than many different variables, and then just assigning that one dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you will have many variables to deal with.  It's not just returning them from the API, it's also dealing with them in your app and perhaps in some processing code.

One solution is to have a big class or struct with many properties.  This will work very well, is straightforward to implement but will require lots of repetitive code. Moreover, it will require to change your API and all your code, whenever some new properties are made available by the remote web service.

Another approach is to have replace the big inflexible class or struct, with a dynamic container, e.g. an array of items `[ Item ]` or a dictionary that associates names to items `[ String : Item ]`.  If the data is just strings, it's straightforward.  If it's several types,  you may have to have to implement a small type system for the elements. Example:

```
var x : [ String: String] = [:]
x["city"]="Strasbourg"
x["temperature"]="34°C"

struct Item {
    var name : String
    var value : String
}
var y : [ Item ] = [Item(name:"city",value:"Strasbourg"),
                    Item(name:"temperature", value:"34°C")]
```

The other advantage of this approach is that you stay loyal to the semantics:  an information that is not available in the API (e.g. "unknown") is not the same as a default value.  I.e. if the weather API does not return a temperature, you will not display 0 in your app.  because 0 is not the same as "unknown".  While strings are more robust in this matter,  the absence of a name is not the same as an empty name.

This last remark suggests that in your current scheme, of having a big data transfer object,  you should consider to keep the properties as optional, and move the responsibility for the processing of unknown data to your app.